# Can we fix the Noah's ark question?

Tags: discussion

This question [Do a significant majority of Americans believe the Noah's Ark story from the Bible is literally true?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6222/do-a-significant-majority-of-americans-believe-the-noahs-ark-story-from-the-bibl) is a reasonable question and although I also like to take a jab at the crazy people that take this stuff literally I think our questions are supposed to be devoid of personal opinions and attacks and should simply ask the question.

I have been pinged on this type of thing before myself and think it's reasonable that we keep this standard.

Is the question "Do a majority of people believe that Noah's ark is a factual story?" or is the question "How is possible that people can believe something so fantastical?".

I think the second one is off topic, because you are not *reeeeeeeally* asking about Noah's ark, you could pick any example from the Bible and know that the same people believe in those also.

We know most people in Group X already think the people in Group Y are crazy for staring down the facts. There's no need to start a *discussion* about this. A better question here is probably do *x* number of people in the US believe that the Bible is based on fact.

---

I've edited the question so it is asking just about the Noah account as per the OP's original question, however I'm not sure whether the OP's intention was to ask about just Noah or about all religious belief.

1. The title was asking about Noah
2. The quote provided was about general belief
3. The two linked claims I cannot verify as I don't want to open a link to coedmagazine it sounds a bit NSFW to me (might contain the occasional T&A) and I can't verify anything from the movie
4. The rest talks about Noah's ark, however the number mentioned "61% of American's" is actually referring to general belief, in the article this is mentioned as "60% of American's" believing in the ark story, which is the statistic I have used

Comment: Good edit; thanks, xiaohouzi79. My only niggling concern is that someone will find a statistic that says "49% of Americans" don't literally believe in Noah's Ark, and declare this dispelled, whereas the spirit of the question is about any significant percentage (i.e. "majority" seems a bit arbitrary, temptingly simplistic though it is). I'll leave it to others to incorporate, as they may, that concern. :)

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt - Feel free to edit it again, I only provided a statistic because you had provided one yourself and I didn't want to deviate too far from what you had written originally. I just wanted to use one that matched the title.

Comment: Linking to coedmagazine for claims is fine - just mark it as "Not safe for work", so no-one gets embarrassed. Linking to it for empirical evidence, however, would be frowned upon!

Comment: @Oddthinking - I am not saying that it is NSFW, I have no idea, just sounds a bit that way. There are a few news sites that are bad enough. I try not to take risks as we have a considerable number of female workers in the office.

Answer (score 1):

The question was edited, so this is resolved (placeholder answer to get this question off the unanswered list).